# Append / Insert button from a HTML page from a domain to another one

Tags: javascript, django, dom, iframe, cross-domain

I have a website and we are creating a plugin button that will be show on our partners website. Something like this green button, on the right of this page:

[image]

The button is already created and it's in a single HTML page on my own domain. The problem is, how to insert it on the partner's website?

Since I can't make javascript requests between different domains, how could I achieve this?

Thanks!!

Comment: `Since I can't make javascript requests between different domains, how could I achieve this?`   what do you mean exactly?, you can of course load javascript from another domain, or things like google maps, jquery cdn's etc wouldn't work.  So you could just create a javascript plugin on your website that they can simple include..  No need for iFrame's etc,..

Comment: Look at the answer of @koolkat below, I think I can't render HTML code, CSS and so on using JS from a domain to another because of cross-site scripting security...

Comment: loading a javascript file and updating the DOM is not a cross-site scripting security issue.   I'm a little confused at what your trying to achieve here,.. Surely you can ask your partners website admin to add a script tag at the bottom of there website to load some javascript from your Domain.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't that clear. As facebook have their Facebook page plugin, or youtube have the EMBED code, I want to do more or less the same (with a button), but I have no idea how, since what I said is not possible... I think, I won't send 300 lines of code to the admin partner's page, would be better to send 5 lines, just an iframe or something like that...

Comment: `I think, I won't send 300 lines of code to the admin partner's page`.. You don't you ask them to add a script tag.. <script src="https://www.mywebsite.com/plugins/partner.js">   This partner.js file will have all your HTML / CSS you need,  ps.  To easily embed CSS & HTML inside a javascript file have a look at webpack.

Comment: Also seen as you mentioned "facebook", & "youtube",.. They both load javascript too.  That's how API's work..  There not just iFrame's that have been embedded.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to render a component on a different domain is a `cross-site scripting` issue. You can probably use `xcomponent` to create `cross-domain components`- 
https://github.com/krakenjs/xcomponent